# Network Drives Aren't Showing After a Successful Mapping in Windows10

Tags: windows-10, inno-setup, network-drive

I'm using InnoSetup script to map a network drive on PC1 to a shared dir on PC2. The command completes successfully but the network drive isn't showing on explorer window, or in 'net use' command of the cmd.

PC1 has Windows 10 pro.
PC2 has Windows Server 2016 Standard.
MySharedFolder folder is shared with read-write access for everyone.
Firewall is down in both machines.
UAC is down in PC1.
The same ADMIN user and password are set for both machines.

I am using 'WScript.Network' object and the method: 'MapNetworkDrive' of it to map the drive. See Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/8kst88h6%28v%3dvs.85%29 
I tried running the command from inno setup with and without credentials and it doesn't work in both ways.

If I run the command manualy from the cmd: 'net use P: \PC1\MySharedDir\P /user:myUserName myPassword' (also without credentials) it works fine and I can see the mapped drive in the explorer window.

How can I map a network drive from inno setup so that it would work and show on my explorer window?

InnoSetup script:

```
#define MyAppName "MyNetworkDriveMappingTest"
#define MyAppVersion "1.5"
#define NEW_LINE '#13#10'

[Setup]
AppId={{975540E2-1D87-43BF-BCBA-0519ED840364}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
CreateAppDir=no
OutputBaseFilename=setup1
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes


[Code]
procedure mapNetworkDriveTest();
var
  WshNetWork : Variant;
  exitCode : Integer;
  driveLetter: String;
  pathToMap: String;
  userToUse: String;
  passwordToUse: String;
  cmdParams: String;

begin
  WshNetWork:=CreateOleObject('WScript.Network');

  driveLetter := 'P';
  pathToMap := '\\PC2\MySharedDir\P';
  userToUse := 'myUserName';
  passwordToUse := 'myPassword';

  if (DirExists(driveLetter+':\')) then
  begin
    WshNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive(driveLetter+':' , true );
    Sleep(1000); // Sleep for 1 second to make sure the command finished properly
  end;


  //  Choose Mapping Drive Method:
  // two methods:
  // 1. cmd
  // 2. 'WScript.Network' object

    // Method 1 - CMD
    //cmdParams := 'net use '+driveLetter+': '+pathToMap+' /user:'+userToUse+' '+passwordToUse;
    //Exec('cmd.exe', '/c '+cmdParams+'', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, exitCode);

    // Method 2 - 'WScript.Network' object
    exitCode := WshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive(driveLetter+':', pathToMap , false , userToUse , passwordToUse);


  if (exitCode <> 0) then
  begin
    MsgBox('Could not map network drive: '''+driveLetter + ''' to path '+pathToMap+{#NEW_LINE}+'CMD Error Code: '+IntToStr(exitCode)+{#NEW_LINE}+'Aborting mapping process of the drive ', mbError, MB_OK);
    Exit;
  end else
  begin
    MsgBox('Mapped network drive: '''+driveLetter + ''' to path '+pathToMap+' successfully', mbConfirmation, MB_OK);
  end;
end;


procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  tempStr: String;
begin
  if (CurStep = ssPostInstall) then
  begin
    mapNetworkDriveTest();
  end;
end;
```

Comment: "*.. or in 'net use' command of the cmd*" - You should test in an elevated command prompt.

Comment: What you mean? I mentioned I did test it "If I run the command manualy from the cmd:.." and it worked. Only if I run it from Inno setup installer it doesn't work.

Comment: After you run it from installer, do your test in an elevated command prompt.

Comment: Drive mappings are per-session, and elevated and non-elevated sessions are separate. Drives mapped from an elevated session are not visible to non-elevated sessions.